# How to set a Java system property in the Jenkins GUI when invoking Ant?

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I have grouped my JUnit tests into several groups and I am only looking to run a single group in a given Jenkins job. To do this, I need to set the Dtestgroup system property to the name of that given test group.

My question is how do I specify this in the Jenkins GUI. I invoke Ant in order to build.

I thought perhaps something like this would accomplish it, but I am not entirely sure. Confirmation/guidance how to set it correctly would be very welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the inline help for Properties says (click on the <kbd>(?)</kbd> icon next to the field), properties should be entered as `name1=value1`.

i.e. Remove the `-D` prefix from your property, and it will work as expected.